# Selecting respective item in drop down list when edit button is clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

I am working on ASP.NET C# web application. I have a `DropDownList` for selecting `machines_names` that is Databound. And a `gridview` which displays stored data. `Gridview` also contains `templateField` for Edit and Delete Buttons. When Edit Button is clicked the stored values of respective fields must be must be loaded on respective field in web form. The problem is when I click edit button, item in ddl (the default value "--select--") is replaced by current data.

I want the stored ddl item to be selected in the ddl when the edit button is clicked.
For example in ddl there are items such as

```
--select--
Roller
Heater
sensor
```

In grid view I have the following

```
Repair-id machine
  1       roller
  2       sensor
```

So when I click edit button of ID 2 in grid view, the ddl must select the third item ie sensor without replacing the top item in ddl.

Here's my code

```
protected DataTable bindMachineName()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dc.Company_code = Convert.ToInt32(Session["Company_Code"].ToString());
        dt = dpbll.select_machine_name(dc);
        ddlMachine.DataSource = dt;
        ddlMachine.DataTextField = "machine_name";
        ddlMachine.DataValueField = "machine_id";
        ddlMachine.DataBind();
        ddlMachine.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("----- Select -----", "-1"));           
    return dt;
}
protected void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dc.Company_code = Convert.ToInt32(Session["company_code"].ToString());
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    GridViewRow gv = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
    string repair_id = gv.Cells[0].Text;
    ViewState["repair_id"] = repair_id;
    ddlMachine.SelectedItem.Text = gv.Cells[1].Text;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind I solved the problem.
`ddlMachine.Items.FindByText(gv.Cells[1].Text` did work perfectly.

```
protected void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dc.Company_code = Convert.ToInt32(Session["company_code"].ToString());
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        GridViewRow gv = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
        string repair_id = gv.Cells[0].Text;
        ViewState["repair_id"] = repair_id;
        ddlMachine.SelectedIndex=ddlMachine.Items.IndexOf(ddlMachine.Items.FindByText(gv.Cells[1].Text));            
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is when I click edit button, item in ddl (the default
>   value "--select--") is replaced by current data.

You might want to set the `DropDownList`'s [`AppendDataBoundItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.appenddatabounditems(v=vs.110).aspx) to `true`.

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlMachine" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
         <asp:ListItem Text="----- Select -----" Value="-1" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

> The `AppendDataBoundItems` property allows you to add items to the
>   ListControl object before data binding occurs. **After data binding, the
>   items collection contains both the items from the data source and the
>   previously added items**.

Comment: I set DropDownList's AppendDataBoundItems to true but it didn't work. Actually I have a database table which has all the stored machine information. I just want to bound the machine name in the DropDownList. 
I want the DropDownList's selected item as the default in its original index (not replacing the top item in the list).